# Javascript OOP : Explain why f.a returns something whereas f.b and c.a returns undefined

Tags: javascript

Explain why f.a returns something whereas f.b and c.a returns undefined. Don't answer : because it's like that or you don't really understand javascript and learn by rotte as Feynman says ;)

```
function f() {
  f.a = "test 1";
  this.b = "test 2";
  return this;
}

let c = f();
console.log(f.a);
console.log(f.b);
console.log(c.a);
```

Comment: Can you explain why you believe that `f.b` and `c.a` _should_ return something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you call `f`, it gives itself (f the Function object) a property of `a` assigned to the string `"test 1"`.

Because `f` is not called with `new`, `this` inside the function body refers to the global object (`window` in the browser, `global` in node). This means the assignment to `this.b` inside the function body is equivalent to `window.b = "test 2"`.

Then the function f returns `this`, which is the `global` object, so `c = global`.

The global object hasn't been assigned a property `a`, so `c.a` is undefined. But `c.b` would be `"test 2"`

Answer (score 2):

f.a returns something, because in the function you assign "test 1" to f.a

this.b is the window
console.log(window.b) will return "test 2"

c is the return of the function
you return "this" and "this" is the window
-> the property a of the window is undefined